# double integrals - finding limits of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

given $$R = \{ x \leq y \leq x +2; -x \leq y \leq 2-x \}$$ find  $$\int \int_R (x-y) \ dA$$

I'm trying to do this question without using a substitution but I'm having troubles finding the limits of integration; I've tried $ -1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $-x \leq y \leq 2-x$ but this isn't the correct region and gives the incorrect answer,

A substitution of $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y$ works but I'd rather not use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by LAcarguy evaluates to $2$; change of variables demands that we take the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian.

If you want to evaluate it directly, then you have to break it up into two parts.

You'll get $$\int_{-1}^{0} \int_{-x}^{x+2} (x-y)\; dy\; dx + \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{2-x} (x-y)\; dy\; dx \\
=  \int_{-1}^{0} x(2x+2) - (x+2)^2/2 + x^2/2\; dx + \int_{0}^{1} x(2-2x) - (2-x)^2/2 + x^2/2\; dx \\
= -4/3 -2/3 \\
= -2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$x\leq y \leq x + 2 \to 0 \leq y - x \leq 2 \to -2 \leq x - y \leq 0$, and

$-x \leq y \leq 2 - x \to 0 \leq x + y \leq 2$. So let:

$u = x + y$, and $v = x - y$, then $\left|\dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right| = -2$. So, the set up of your double-integral is:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^2 \int_{-2}^0 -\dfrac{v}{2}dvdu$

Comment: Thanks - I used that when I was asked the question but was wondering if there was a way without using the substitution.